# What symbol denotes "or more"?

Tags: sentence, symbols

Trying to construct a math-like means for my English students to understand sentence structure.  Need to indicate: "A compound sentence consists of 2 Independent Clauses and 1 **OR MORE** Dependent Clauses."

The final "formula" will look like:
Cp = 2IC + 1 (NEED THE SYMBOL FOR "OR MORE" HERE) DC

Comment: Maybe `Cp = 2IC + (DC >= 1)`

Comment: Or CS = (n>1)IC + (n>0)DC. A Compound sentence may have more than 2 IC.

Comment: Borrowing from regular expression syntax: DC{1,}

Comment: Compound sentences can consist of just two independent clauses joined by a conjunction or semicolon. I think you are trying to describe a compound/complex sentence.

Comment: Probably a bad idea.  (Unless these are technically inclined students trying to learn English.)  Instead write it in words.

Answer (score 2):

I agree [GEdgar's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121587/what-symbol-denotes-or-more#comment250031_121587) that for the sake of clarity, explaining what you mean in plain, simple English would generally be best. But to answer your question, you might want to consider a superscript *plus*, perhaps replacing the other *plus* with something else to avoid confusion:

> Cp = 2IC + 1<sup>+</sup>DC
>
> Cp = 2IC + 1<sub>+</sub>DC
>
> Cp = 2IC, 1<sup>+</sup>DC
>
> Cp = 2IC, 1<sub>+</sub>DC

Or possibly use a [*greater than or equal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_%28mathematics%29) to symbol:

> Cp = 2IC + n<sup>≥1</sup>DC
>
> Cp = 2IC + n<sub>≥1</sub>DC

You could use just the *greater than or equal* symbol, but with a *plus* this looks pretty weird:

> Cp = 2IC + ≥1DC

This is much better:

> Cp = 2IC, ≥1DC

Comment: I like your superscripted '+' idea; after all, "N+" is informal for "N or more," such as is found in the phrases "3+ grams of fiber per day"; "4+ years of experience desired"; or "10+ assists per game." Of course, a plain '+' doesn't work well in a math equation, but the superscripted + fixes that nicely, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using notation that implies you're adding a quantity of DC that exists in the set of [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Your equation would look something like this:

```
Cp = 2IC + DC * a∈ℕ
```

Where a is any number in the set of natural numbers.